# tkinter empty variable for entry inserted into database

Tags: python, database, tkinter

so i wrote this code to connect to the database and insert or return some data from it
but i when i want to insert there's no data to be inserted into database, I mean the row is created in the table but it's an empty row and the problem should be from somewhere like `usersign.get()`

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
import time
def MainWindow():
    global tk
    tk = Tk()
    tk.geometry('300x340')
    tk.title("Login")
    label = Label(tk, text="Enter Your Credentials", fg="black")
    label.pack(side="top", pady="15px")
    label2 = Label(tk, text="Username")
    label2.pack(expand=True)
    userlog = StringVar()
    userentry = Entry(tk, width=20, textvariable=userlog)
    userentry.pack(expand=True)
    label3 = Label(tk, text="Password")
    label3.pack()
    passlog = StringVar()
    passentry = Entry(tk, width=20, textvariable=passlog)
    passentry.pack()
    login = Button(tk, text="Login", bg="gray")
    login.pack(pady="15px")
    forgot = Button(tk, text="Forgot password", bg="white", command=lambda: forgotpassword())
    forgot.pack()
    btn2 = Button(tk, text="Sign Up", bg="white", command=Signup)
    btn2.pack(expand=True)
    tk.mainloop()
def Withdraw():
    tk2.withdraw()
    tk.deiconify()
def forgotpassword():
    global tk2
    tk.withdraw()
    tk2 = Tk()
    tk2.geometry('300x340')
    tk2.title("Forgot Password")
    lbl = Label(tk2, text="Username")
    lbl.pack(side="top", expand=True)
    userforgot = StringVar()
    usr = Entry(tk2, width=20, textvariable=userforgot)
    usr.pack(expand=True)
    lbl2 = Label(tk2, text="Phone Number")
    lbl2.pack(expand=True)
    phoneforgot = StringVar()
    phone = Entry(tk2, width=20, textvariable=phoneforgot)
    phone.pack(expand=True)
    btn = Button(tk2, text="Forgot Password", bg="white", command=PassRecovery())
    btn.pack(expand=True)
def PassRecovery():
    #connectes to database
    #checks if datas match or not
    # if so, creates a label showing the data
    Btn = Button(tk2, text="Return to login window", command=lambda: Withdraw())
    Btn.pack(expand=True)
def Signup():
    global tk3, usersign, passsign, phonesign
    # the problem is that globalization is happening before the assignment of variables
    tk.withdraw()
    tk3 = Tk()
    tk3.geometry('300x340')
    tk3.title("Sign Up")
    lbl = Label(tk3, text="Username")
    lbl.pack(expand=True)
    usersign = StringVar()
    ent1 = Entry(tk3, textvariable=usersign, width=20)
    ent1.pack(expand=True)
    lbl2 = Label(tk3, text="Password")
    lbl2.pack(expand=True)
    passsign = StringVar()
    ent2 = Entry(tk3, textvariable=passsign, width=20)
    ent2.pack(expand=True)
    print(passsign.get())
    phonesign = StringVar()
    lbl3 = Label(tk3, text="Phone Number")
    lbl3.pack(expand=True)
    ent3 = Entry(tk3, textvariable=phonesign, width=20)
    ent3.pack(expand=True)
    btn = Button(tk3, text="Sign Up", command=lambda: InsertData())
    btn.pack(expand=True)
    print(usersign.get())
def InsertData():
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="Balarooch1386")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("use usercredentials")
    cursor.execute("insert into data values (%s, %s, %s)", (usersign.get(), passsign.get(), phonesign.get()))
    db.commit()
    labl = Label(tk3, text="Signed Up Successfully")
    labl.pack(expand=True)
    print(usersign.get())
    # tk3.withdraw()
    # tk.deiconify()
MainWindow()
#issue : no data to insert into table
```

i tried putting all the functions in `MainWindow()` but it didn't work

Comment: The issue is caused by multiple instances of `Tk()`.  For windows other than the main window, use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()`.

Comment: thanks man it worked but why did this make it work?

Comment: tkinter variable (like `StringVar`) has `master` which by default the first instance of `Tk()` when it is not specified.  Widgets in other instance of `Tk()` cannot update tkinter variable in the first instance of `Tk()`.